# About a map between $A$ and $eAe$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a fin. dim. $k$-algebra and $e \in A$ be an idempotent.
Let  $f: A \rightarrow eAe$ be a map such that

$f(e_i)=e_i$ if $e_i \in eAe$

$f(e_i)=0$ otherwise.

I think it may not be an algebra homomorphism. But at least can we say that it is a $k$-linear map?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? People here like to see the effort s you made. Also does `fin. dim.` means `finite dimension`?

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is finite dimensional. In fact I work on the map $f: A \rightarrow eAe $ which maps $e_i$ to $e_i$ if $e_i \in eAe$ and to zero otherwise. I think it may not be an algebra homomorphism. But I wonder that maybe is it an $k$-linear map? Or can not we talk about the general situation?

Comment: you should include this in the post. Most people don't read the comments.

Comment: I did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sometimes you cannot get a ring homomorphism from $A$ onto $eAe$.  For example, let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix ring over a field $F$, and $e$ be the matrix that is 1 in the first diagonal position and zero elsewhere.  $A$ does not have any nontrivial quotients, and none of its trivial quotients are isomorphic to $eAe=F$.

The map $x\mapsto exe$ is a surjective homomorphism of groups, though, and also is $k$ linear.

In general, $A\cong eAe\oplus eA(1-e)\oplus (1-e)Ae\oplus (1-e)A(1-e)$ as abelian groups, and if $A$ is a k algebra, as k vector spaces.  You’ve just chosen the projection onto the first factor for your map.

Comment: I edited my question. The map which I defined is also $k$-linear?

Comment: @sm.s what is preventing you from checking if it is linear or not by yourself?

Comment: I actually checked it. But I just thought maybe it can change for the general case.